# drop down with 2 options, then questions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying am making a dropdown with 2 questions in it. Say question A and question B. Either option they will get 3 more questions they will answer with a number 1-10. Right now if they choose A it works perfect. But if they select B, the second option it does not work. I have been looking for a way to do this for days and I'm amazed I can't find a easy way. I don't understand why this don't work because what ever they input will go to box1, box2 or box3 anyway. This is my  fiddle

$('.myOptions').change(function(){

```
$('.list').removeClass('active')
.filter('.' + $('.myOptions').children('option:selected').attr('value'))
.addClass('active');
```

});

$('#butt').click(function () {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the value of the options is not the same as the classes assigned to `.list` elements

The solution is to change the values of options to `owner` and `not-owner`

```
<option value="owner">Owner</option>
<option value="not-owner">Not Owner</option>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G24aQ/)

If you do not want to change the value of the options, then you can introduce a new attribute to fix the problem

```
<option data-type="owner" value="under 45 years old">Owner</option>
<option data-type="not-owner" value="over 45 years old">Not Owner</option>
```

Then

```
$('.list').removeClass('active').filter('.' + $('.myOptions').children('option:selected').data('type'))
.addClass('active');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G24aQ/2/)

**Update:**
Another problem is the duplicate ids assigned to the input elements, here the solution I would suggest is to use class instead of id and then get the input values from active `list` element.

```
<div class="list owner">
    <p>a</p>
    <input class="box1" type="text" size="2"/><br/>
    <p>b</p>
    <input class="box2" type="text" size="2"/><br/>
    <p>c</p>
    <input class="box3" type="text" size="2"/><br/>
    <!-- questions for owners -->
</div>

<div class="list not-owner">
    <p>x</p>
    <input class="box1" type="text" size="2"/><br/>    
    <p>y</p>
    <input class="box2" type="text" size="2"/><br/>
    <p>z</p>
    <input class="box3" type="text" size="2"/><br/>
    <!-- questions for non-owners -->
</div>
```

Then

```
var active = $('.list.active');

var $boxOne = active.find('.box1');
var k1 = parseInt($boxOne.val(), 10);
var $boxTwo = active.find('.box2');
var k2 = parseInt($boxTwo.val(), 10);

var $boxThree = active.find('.box3');
var k3 = parseInt($boxThree.val(), 10);
var total = k1 + k2 + k3;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G24aQ/4/)

Comment: still don't work try it. pick the second option. will say no impute. you are right but i did have the wrong values too.

Comment: @user2537145, it is because you have duplicate id attribute values, id should be unique in a document

Comment: Arun P Johny your the man!!! you don't know how long i was trying to do that for!!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you're selecting the `option` value, and you're actually looking for the text:

```
$('.myOptions').change(function(){
    var optionText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $('.list').removeClass('active').filter('.' + optionText).addClass('active');
});
```

It's also searching for a class of `not-owner` when your text says `Not Owner`, two very different things.